# Why do some Blackbox challenges have a border around them?

Tags: blackbox

On the home screen of [Blackbox](http://blackboxpuzzles.com), most challenges appear as a box which is filled in with a solid color once completed. However, there are a few challenges which have an extra outline around them.

Why do some challenges have an extra outline around them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Challenges with borders are known as “meta challenges”.

According to Blackbox’s developer on the [official Discord server](https://discord.gg/blackbox):

> Meta challenges themselves are not necessarily harder than any other challenge but they are not revealed by simply progressing through the game; they often take extra steps to find, reveal, and/or unlock.